# How to get the data from a document in firebase using its id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the products from Firebase where all the products are in different documents with different IDs. The IDE prompts that data() is not defined for the object type, I don't know how to get away with it. The issue is in the if block where I check snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done within the Future builder

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_fashion/Constants/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter_fashion/Views/Widgets/action_bar.dart';

class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;

  const ProductPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.id,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CollectionReference _productsRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
              future: _productsRef.doc(id).get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Error: ${snapshot.error}",
                        style: Constants.regularDarkText,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data!.data();
                  return ListView(
                    children: [
                      Image.network(documentData['Image'])
                    ],
                    );
                }
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xFFFF1E00)),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
          ActionBar(title: "ProductPage", hasBackArrow: true, hasTitle: false)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell the error?

Comment: The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Comment: You should mention the type of the builder's snapshot argument as `AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`, Otherwise it will be an AsyncSnapshot<Object> type. So, you can't access the data() method from the DocumentSnapshot and QuerySnapshot classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have just modified the code by replacing the StreamBuilder. Please check the following code snippets.

```
class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;

  const ProductPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.id,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("Products")
                  .doc(id)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                      snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Error: ${snapshot.error}",
                        style: Constants.regularDarkText,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  Map<String, dynamic>? documentData = snapshot.data?.data();
                  return ListView(
                    children: [Image.network(documentData!['Image'])],
                  );
                }
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xFFFF1E00)),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
          ActionBar(title: "ProductPage", hasBackArrow: true, hasTitle: false)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its returning scaffold with circular progress indicator only

Comment: Can you check the second if condition with snapshot.hasData instead of connection state logic?

Comment: Sometimes, I got the same issue when I'm working with the connection state. That times, I resolved the issues by checking the snapshot data. However, I don't know either.

Comment: Since I added snapshot.hasData there is a bit of glitch type happening before the products get correctly loaded any idea ?

Comment: May be the delay of getting the data from the firebase I guess. I don't know exact reason.